# Spring boot - Validating request body json key

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am working on validating the request body in Spring boot.
When the post controller using the below JSON to create record in the DB. It works fine.

```
{
  "test1": "string",
  "test2": "string",
  "test3": "string",  <--this has @Null in the entity
  "test4": "string"
}
```

However, when one of the key is @NULL in the entity, it will still able to create a record in the DB. I am wondering if there is something that can validate the key and return error.

```
{
  "test1": "string",
  "test2": "string",
  "test5": "string", <- wrong key by mistake
  "test4": "string"
}
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Test implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "test1")
private String test1;

@Column(name = "test2")
@NotNull
private String test2;

@Column(name = "test3")
private String test3;

@Column(name = "test4")
private String test4;
}
```

Comment: is it `@Null` or `@NotNull`. Is it possible to give a minimal reproducible piece of code, so that we can get the context better and help

Comment: it is @Null, so if the field is misspelled, it will show up "test3" = null since it is able null value.

Comment: added the example entity class that test1 is id, test2 is not null, test3 and test4 allow null value.

Comment: @NotNull(message = "<your message>") you can give the message

Comment: It suppose to allow null value for test3 and test4. When the request JSON doesn't have "test3", it will replace null value instead. If user makes a mistake on the field "test3" -> "test5", it won't tell the error.

Comment: that is not a property of the entity per se, when you are de-serializing the message to  Object, you can configure it to say it wont have additional fields but will work against backward compatibility to your apis. So would not recommend you to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/) for parsing JSON and handle unknown properties. It will automatically throw UnrecognizedPropertyException if an unknown property is found as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties#1-unrecognizedpropertyexception-on-unknown-fields)

Answer (score 0):

```
If u want to Validate request body in JSON u can use @Valid

      @PostMapping("/books")
    Book newBook(@Valid @RequestBody Test test) {
        return repository.save(Test);
    }

@Column(name = "test3")
@NotNull(message = "Please provide a test3")
private String test3;

if u want on key order
 JsonPropertyOrder({ "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" })
public class Test implements Serializable {
}
```